# Fixed orientation for a view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my app I've a `UITabBarController` that contains 3 `UINavigationController`. I can freeze orientation for any `UIViewController`. For this I've implemented `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController`. But problem occurs when I push a `UIViewController` from another one that was in Landscape. The newly pushed UIViewController should be in portrait but it remains in Landscape. I know problem may be unclear so I am attaching scrrenshots.

Lets consider its VC-A.

[image]

Pressing edit from VC-A goes to this VC-B. VC-B is:

[image]

This VC-B should always in portrait. VC-A can be in Landscape or portrait. When VC-A is in landscape and I press **edit** the VC-B is pushed and VC-B comes in landscape mode though I implemented these methods in VC-B:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `shouldAutorotate` needs to return a BOOL not the mask, so code should be

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thats not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All child view controllers in a tab bar controller or navigation controller must have the same set of supported orientations. This is discussed near the bottom of the following document.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1688/_index.html